# Keras parallel layers merging

Tags: keras, concatenation

I read Keras documentation, but had not found any explanation on the following error
Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Reshape, Flatten
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

data = pd.read_excel('oildata.xlsx')

firstBranch = Sequential()
#firstBranch.add(Reshape((1,28,28), input_shape=(,)))
firstBranch.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(10, 1100)))
#firstBranch.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
firstBranch.add(Flatten())

secondBranch = Sequential()

secondBranch.add(BatchNormalization(name = 'batch_norm_0', input_shape = (1000, 10, 1, 1)))
secondBranch.add(ConvLSTM2D(name ='conv_lstm_1',
                     filters = 64, kernel_size = (10, 1),                       
                     padding = 'same', 
                     return_sequences = False))

secondBranch.add(Dropout(0.10, name = 'dropout_1'))
secondBranch.add(BatchNormalization(name = 'batch_norm_1'))

#     model.add(ConvLSTM2D(name ='conv_lstm_2',
#                          filters = 64, kernel_size = (5, 1), 
#                          padding='same',
#                          return_sequences = False))

#     model.add(Dropout(0.20, name = 'dropout_2'))
#     model.add(BatchNormalization(name = 'batch_norm_2'))
secondBranch.add(Flatten())
secondBranch.add(RepeatVector(1000))
secondBranch.add(Reshape((1000, 10, 1, 64)))

#     model.add(ConvLSTM2D(name ='conv_lstm_3',
#                          filters = 64, kernel_size = (10, 1), 
#                          padding='same',
#                          return_sequences = True))

#     model.add(Dropout(0.20, name = 'dropout_3'))
#     model.add(BatchNormalization(name = 'batch_norm_3'))

 secondBranch.add(ConvLSTM2D(name ='conv_lstm_4',
                     filters = 64, kernel_size = (5, 1), 
                     padding='same',
                     return_sequences = True))

secondBranch.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=1, name = 'dense_1', activation = 'relu')))
secondBranch.add(Dense(units=1, name = 'dense_2'))
secondBranch.add(Flatten())

thirdBranch = Sequential()
thirdBranch.add(Reshape((1,28,28), input_shape=(784,)))
thirdBranch.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))

thirdBranch.add(Flatten())

fourthBranch = Sequential()
#fourthBranch.add(Reshape((1,28,28), input_shape=(784,)))
fourthBranch.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))

fourthBranch.add(Flatten())

#merged = Concatenate([firstBranch, secondBranch, thirdBranch,fourthBranch], mode='concat')
merged = Concatenate([firstBranch,secondBranch,thirdBranch,fourthBranch])

model = Sequential()
model.add(merged)
model.add(Dense(28*3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(19))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))


sgd = SGD(lr=0.5, momentum=0.8, decay=0.1, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([X,X,X,X],X, batch_size=100, verbose=2)

yPred = model.predict([X,X,X,X],X)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-385-11a86cc54884> in <module>
     88 sgd = SGD(lr=0.5, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
     89 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 90 model.fit([X,X,X,X],X, batch_size=100, verbose=2)
     91 
     92 yPred = model.predict([X,X,X,X],X)
...........................................

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ListWrapper"
```

What does it mean `ListWrapper`? Data is turned into frames and had to fit the model.

Comment: Your code does not define `X`.

Comment: I had assigned each variable with numpy array data - single_step_model.fit([X_left, X_right], Y_train, validation_split=0.2), X_left - multidimensional, X_right,  Y_train - 1 dimension for two components model instead of four. And error is just the same.